# Flask blueprint doesn't work without prefix

Tags: python, flask

Hi I have a Flask app structured in following way and I have problem with blueprints setup. Whatever I do, they only work with `url_prefix` set up. It works currently as `/main/verify` but as it is a small app I would love to have an endpoint like `/verify`. What's interesting I managed to make it work with `/` route, but for the same configuration it didn't work for the `/verify`. I am pretty clueless right now, I can live with it as it is, but I really wonder what am I doing wrong.

Here is the code:

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config


db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)

    from main import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

`main/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/main')
from . import views
```

`main/views.py`

```
from flask import request, jsonify
from . import main


@main.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world"


@main.route('/verify')
def verify():
    url = request.args['url']
    query = request.args['query']

    return jsonify({ ... })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I see you didn't register `blueprint` without prefix. If you need to register endpoints without prefix you must create a new instance of `Blueprint`

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/main')
# main endpoints(with prefix /main)...
@main.route('/')
def index_main():
    return "Hello world from /main/"
# routes without any prefix
default = Blueprint('default', __name__)

@default.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world from /"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main)
app.register_blueprint(default)
```

Hope this helps.